# How to show data is null in ASP.NET Web API when database having null values?

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

I am calling my database from my ASP.Net Web API as

```
 [HttpGet]
    public  IActionResult GetOutput(int id)
    {
        string CheckJob = "exec sp_GetJob "+ "@id= " + id;

        var result = _context.Job.FromSqlRaw(CheckJob).ToList().FirstOrDefault().Job;
        if(result == null){
               -- do other functions
        }
       return Ok(result);
    }
```

And My class is

```
 public class Job
    {
     public int Job {get;set;}
    }
```

And If for particular input, if value is not available then it should store null value in my variable result. But It is showing error as

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'

Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetJob @id
AS
DECLARE @JobID AS int
BEGIN
set @JobID = ( select JobId from Config 
                  where id = @id)

SELECT @JobID AS Job
END
```

Can someone tell me if, If database is return null value then how to store null value in variable so that I can compare that variable to go forward ?

Thank you

Comment: define variable as `int?` to allow null values

Comment: I did, but it is not working

Comment: You can check with `if (CheckJob != DBNull.Value)` before doing any operation

Comment: I guess calling my stored procedure, there is some error. But I am not able to find

Comment: Debug the proc in the MS SSMS (assuming Sql Sever is your Db engine).

Comment: @Serg my stored procedure looks fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the nullable value type.

```
public class Job
{
    public int? Job {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: It is not working